# How I can generate patch from RAD ready to deploy in WAS?

Tags: ibm, patch-management, websphere, was7

To use update option directly from IBM WAS-ND , I need to generate patch file from RAD ready to deploy ( already packaged ) .

Example :
After Deploy HelloWord.ear on WAS-ND 7.0.11 , an exception appear , to fix this exception a class x.calss and y.class should be updated ,how i can generate a full patch from this classes and deploy it directly on WAS .

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere doesn't support updating individual class files; the smallest updateable unit would be a JAR file inside an EAR.

Once you fixed your code, export the module (in which your updated classes reside) through RAD. Then, using the WebSphere Admin Console (or scripting), follow the instructions to "Update Application". You can then choose exactly which JAR/WAR/RAR to update.

Comment: In WAS 7.0.0 there are option to deploy single file ( update -> update/add/delete single file) . please check it